# Can't rename a subdirectory of a mounted pendrive

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu

I built a script to rename all sub directories of a specific directory (change to uppercase the first letter) using 'mv' command. Unfortunately that wasn't possible and I got the error (below is an example):

**cannot move 'mechanics' to a subdirectory of itself,    'Mechanics/mechanics'**

```
  #!/bin/bash

for name in *
    do
        if [ -d "$name" ]; then
                echo "$name"
        newname="$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< ${name:0:1})${name:1}"    
        mv "$name" "$newname"

    fi
done
```

How can I workaround this?

Comment: Please add the exact command you try to exec

Comment: can u share the part of the script and full path of subdirectory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hypothesis: the filesystem is case insensitive and therefore `Mechanics` and `mechanics` address the same directory.

It may be possible to rename `mechanics` to `Mechanics` via a temporary name:

```
mv mechanics foo
mv foo Mechanics
```

Then the directory may appear as `Mechanics` but you will still be able to refer to it as `mechanics` or even `mECHaniCS`.

Answer (score 0):

You script is correct, but you already have a **Mechanics** folder in your current directory along with **mechanics** folder because of which you are getting the error.

Comment: You should put a condition inside the loop that checks if the targeted folder is already having an uppercase letter in the beginning or not. `echo $name | grep -v [^A-Z]` will give status 1 if it is not a name with an uppercase letter in the start.

Comment: I don't have a 'Mechanics' folder alongside with a 'mechanics' folder.